# angular js data table issue with nested object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I am using angular js datatable for my project. Currently I am trying to access below object,

```
       "finalizedArr":[ 
      { 
         "treaceId":"KYC454353545", 
         "approval":[   
            {   
               "usr":"kalindu kumara",  
               "threshold":100  
            },  
            {   
               "usr":"kuma kalil",  
               "threshold":80   
            },  
]}
]
```

I am using below code sample to generate table. This is the main part code

```
   $scope.dtColumns = [
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('traceId').withTitle('Trace ID'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('approval.usr').withTitle('Name'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('approval.threshold').withTitle('Match Strength %')
];
```

When I use this code, treaceId column is correctly rendered in the table. but 'usr' and 'threshold' not rendered. I think reason is ,usr and threshold inside the array. but i do not know how to modify this. Can you check my issue

Answer (score 1):

Out-of-the-box ngTable dynamic expects `column.field` to be property names, not navigators. (i.e. it doesn't handle dot syntax `oneProperty.anotherProperty` as it effectively does `columnObject["fieldNameYouProvided"]`)

You could try a similar solution as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25958914/4096074) or you could try mapping your data model to a flat object.

Lastly, `approval.usr` and `approval.threshold` are not valid property accessors for the provided data model because approval is an array so to access the first values you would access them with `approval[0].usr` and `approval[0].threshold` which will not work as a dynamic column field property value for the aformentioned reasons.